# Jquery add div to page ontop of everything else with draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a application I am attempting to extend the functionality of it. As that is the case the html in this example must be added with JavaScript. The requirement is when the page is loaded a div will be added to the page and it will become draggable. This happens but since the div is added with prepend it takes up space and there is some 'grey' space when the div is dragged around.

```
$('.body').prepend('<div style="height:40px; width 40px; z-index:9; position:relative;" id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content"><p>test</p></div>');
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
});
```

Comment: `position: relative` moves the element without disrupting the original document flow (caused by the elements presence). You might want to use `position: absolute`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess , you need to position it `absolute`

`position:absolute;`